# Stripe invoice.payment_failed doesn`t work

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, payment

I have a usage-metered plan in Stripe and I'm trying to use this:

```
./stripe.exe trigger invoice.payment_failed --add invoice:metadata.userId=7 --override payment_method:customer=cus_id123 --add invoice:metadata.userId=7 --override invoiceitem:customer=cus_id123 --override invoice:customer=cus_id123 --add invoice:metadata.userId=7
```

For some reason I can't figure it out, it returns all possible events up to success, except the one I need most which is invoice.payment_failed. I'm using the card:
4000000000000341 and to get value inside the generated cus_id I use the service several times, but when I activate the above command to test it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

There are some duplicate flags in your command but I assume you're trying to trigger a failed invoice payment for a specific customer and also want to add the metadata `userId: 7` to the invoice. If that's accurate, here's the command you want:

```
./stripe.exe trigger invoice.payment_failed --skip customer --override payment_method:customer=cus_id123 --override invoiceitem:customer=cus_id123 --override invoice:customer=cus_id123 --add invoice:metadata.userId=7
```

I'll explain each flag:

- The [invoice.payment_failed trigger](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-cli/blob/e776ffe43d03e65d4105d81bd5d12043ec3291d8/pkg/fixtures/triggers/invoice.payment_failed.json) creates a brand-new customer. You should skip the `customer` fixture if you want to specify a customer for this failed invoice payment.
- Each the `payment_method`, `invoiceitem`, and `invoice` fixtures that follow all reference the customer created in the `customer` fixture. Since you skipped the `customer` fixture, you should override the customer parameter with your test customer ID for each of these fixtures.
- Pass `--add invoice:metadata.userId=7` in your command once to add metadata to the invoice object.